# Repeating over a list Polymer broken

Tags: dart, polymer

Update: problem with bleeding edge editor not being compatible with the version of serialization/polymer on pub. Need to install versions from SVN.

Repeating over a list appears to have been broken to me.

https://github.com/sethladd/dart-polymer-dart-examples/blob/master/web/bind_and_repeat_over_list_of_primitives/

This is the simplest example I could find and I get the same error:

Internal error: 'package:serialization/src/serialization_helpers.dart': Error: line 212 pos 7: unresolved implicit call to super constructor 'LinkedHashMap()'
class IdentityMap extends LinkedHashMap {
      ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this update from #dartlang 10 Sep 2013 :-

'New Dart release with search improvements in Editor, and more.

SDK changes include:

HashMap and LinkedHashmap cannot be extended anymore......'

Looks as though Polymer needs updating for this.

Comment: Yup, I figured that might have had to do with it. I guess I should file a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the code slightly and make it work.

Change the `index.html` file to look like this:

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>index</title>
    <script src="packages/polymer/boot.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <template id="tmpl" bind>
        <template repeat="{{}}">
          <li>{{}}</li>
        </template>
      </template>
    </ul>
    <script type="application/dart" src="index.dart"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And your `index.dart` should look like this (it is unchanged):

```dart
import 'dart:html';

main() {
  List fruits = ['apples', 'oranges', 'pears'];
  query('#tmpl').model = fruits;
}
```

You bind to a template that contains the template where the `repeat` is registered. the `{{}}` in `repeat="{{}}"`refers to the bound value. The `{{}}` in the `<li>{{}}</li>` refers to each item in the list.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Its a bug with the new SDK (bleeding edge build) not with the stable build.